# John Dalton's temperature scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, history

Could some one give me a brief explanation of what Dalton's temperature scale is?
I have tried to refer to understand this scale but there are not that much information out there in the internet.
Links to some information?

Comment: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2341177

Comment: This would be better for hsm.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for HMS.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a historical curiosity. It’s a logarithmic scale and isn’t proportional to thermal energy. On this scale, negative infinity is the coldest temperature (what we know as “absolute zero”), water freezes at 0 and boils at 100, and lead melts at 253. The formulas for converting to and from absolute temperature are

$$T_\text{Kelvin} = 273.15\left(\frac{373.15}{273.15}\right)^{T_\text{Dalton}/100}$$

$$T_\text{Dalton} = 100\frac{\log{T_\text{Kelvin}}-\log{273.15}}{\log{373.15}-\log{273.15}}$$

When the temperature increases by 738.1 on the Dalton scale, it increases by a factor of 10 on the Kelvin scale. Here is a table where you can see how the logarithmic Dalton scale represents a huge range of absolute temperatures from one trillionth of a degree Kelvin to one trillion degrees Kelvin :

\begin{array}{cr}
 T_\text{Kelvin} & T_\text{Dalton} \\
 10^{-12} & -10655.6 \\
 10^{-11} & -9917.46 \\
 10^{-10} & -9179.36 \\
 10^{-9} & -8441.25 \\
 10^{-8} & -7703.15 \\
 10^{-7} & -6965.05 \\
 10^{-6} & -6226.94 \\
 10^{-5} & -5488.84 \\
 10^{-4} & -4750.73 \\
 10^{-3} & -4012.63 \\
 10^{-2} & -3274.53 \\
 10^{-1} & -2536.42 \\
 10^{0} & -1798.32 \\
 10^{1} & -1060.21 \\
 10^{2} & -322.110 \\
 10^{3} & 415.995 \\
 10^{4} & 1154.10 \\
 10^{5} & 1892.20 \\
 10^{6} & 2630.31 \\
 10^{7} & 3368.41 \\
 10^{8} & 4106.52 \\
 10^{9} & 4844.62 \\
 10^{10} & 5582.72 \\
 10^{11} & 6320.83 \\
 10^{12} & 7058.93 \\
\end{array}

https://www.curiousnotions.com/temperature-converter/

https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Dalton%27s+temperature+scale

Today, if you wanted to work with a logarithmic temperature scale, it would probably make sense to just use some logarithm (either natural or base-10) of the Kelvin temperature rather than sticking in constants to make it have nice values for water freezing and boiling.